# Send parameters to control defined in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to send parameters to a control defined in a XAML?
For example if I have this XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Colors.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Polygon x:Name="plgPoly" Points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,0" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But when I construct my "Polygon" I want to give it coordinates which depend on the control which contain it (like : this.Height, this.Width, etc...) or on other controls defined in the parent control.
Is it possible? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the property that should reference another is a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) that can easily be done via a [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) (with [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx)), otherwise you may need to construct your own [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) that fetches the value once (rather than binding it).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only a simple value or bind to a custom property of owner control, use dependency property mechanism as suggested by **H.B.**. It is, however, probable, that you would need to convert a value from another type to appropriate one (i.e. `PointCollection`). In this case, I would suggest using a binding and a value converter to do it. More on value converters can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx.

Comment: I think I can define my own PointsCollection in <Grid.Resources> and then just bind my polygon to it. I'll do the binding within the definition. This will solve the problem, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is satisfying in your case, however, you can find some information about binding to resources here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752326.aspx#creating.